# How do I minimize repeated xml attributes when dealing with multiple levels of inheritance?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance

I have a UI framework for an XNA engine written that currently makes it easy to define user interfaces via code.  I am looking at making it easier to utilize by allowing the defining of user interfaces via XML.

What I'm stuck on is creating the deserialization classes.  The issue is that the root contains a collection of items, and some items may contain one or more child items.  Right now I have something similar to:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class RootClass
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem("ClassA", typeof(ClassA)]
    [XmlArrayItem("ClassB", typeof(ClassB)]
    public List<BaseClass> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set;
}

public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AValue { get; set;

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem("ClassA", typeof(ClassA)]
    [XmlArrayItem("ClassB", typeof(ClassB)]
    public List<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string BValue { get; set;

    [XmlElement("ClassA", typeof(ClassA)]
    [XmlElement("ClassB", typeof(ClassB)]
    public BaseClass SingleChild { get; set; }
}
```

The intention of this is that the root can contain any number of subclasses, but the `ClassA` elements can contain any number of child classes, while the `ClassB` type may contain a single child class.

This has a massive maintainability issue because when I add a new class that inherits from `BaseClass` (such as `ClassC`), I need to add a new `XmlArrayItem` attribute to the `RootClass.Classes` property *and* to every other list that is used.  If `ClassC` also contains a list of classes, then that is now 3 points I need to maintain the `XmlArrayItem` attribute listings.  I also need to make sure any single class values have a new `[XmlElement]` attribute added to them.

Is there an easier way to keep from having to repeat these inheritance mappings across every deserialization class?

Comment: The problem with that is if I need a class that does not inherit from `BaseClass` but does still requires children, I still have the same issue (for example, a Grid may have a collection of cells, each cell has only one child) (this was a reply to someone asking why I can't create another inherited layer for a base class with children)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to implement **IXmlSerializable** I think. 
I have done this in my own project to handle the serialization and deserialization of a complex inheritance. You can "control" the de/serialization with ReadXml/WriteXml methods that are overwritten by child classes.

Implementing IXmlSerializable on your own is much more better if you have some "dynamic" mechanism in your framework, like extending the classes by types that are loaded during the runtime of the program or if you dont want to edit your attributes every time. If you go this way, you have to serialize the Type of the class. And at deserialization time you can create the object via "Activator" and the type you have serialized.